# Can Solaris' shadow hashes be created by better algorithms than the default DES-based hash?

Tags: cryptography, hash, unix

By default, Solaris uses Traditional DES to encrypt password hashes in the shadow file.

Is there a way to harden the security by changing this default behaviour and make it to be hashed using a stronger algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose the algorithm used between one of [these](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/concept-28.html#concept-encralg-1) (older Solaris releases might not have all of them available):

- Traditional Unix crypt
- BSD/Linux compatible md5
- Blowfish
- SHA256
- SHA512

To [change the algorithms](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/secsys-15.html) accepted for existing passwords and used for new ones, modify the `CRYPT_ALGORITHMS_ALLOW` and `CRYPT_DEFAULT` variables in `/etc/security/policy.conf` file.

This is based on plugins so should you want custom encryption methods, you can [install third party ones](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23823_01/html/816-4557/secsystask-42.html#secsys-13) or develop your own.

Comment: I assume the SHA and BSD/Linux compatible MD5 algorithms are also used in a UNIX crypt() fashion? So they don't just hash, but also salt and stretch?

Comment: I would say they do it from reading the source code: http://cvs.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/crypt_modules/sha256/crypt_sha.c

Comment: http://dropsafe.crypticide.com/article/1389 is a blog post from one of the co-authors of the Solaris enhanced crypt() (as well as the classic _Crack_ password cracker) with more implementation details.